# Out-of-date IMAP back-up - restore emails from Client?

Tags: backup, dovecot, imap, synchronization, thunderbird

The IMAP server just died (Dovecot with Maildirs). 
The back-up is 1 day old. 
The missing day of emails is available on the Thunderbird local client.
If the IMAP server is restored from backup, on sync, will the local email on the Thunderbird client be wiped out?
What is the best way of transferring these emails back on to the server?

Comment: 1) Ensure thunderbird computer can't connect to IMAP server (turn off wifi/pull the LAN cable) 2) Run Thunderbird 3) While offline **Copy** email from IMAP account to *Thunderbird Local Folder* 4) Connect thunderbird to IMAP server 5)  **Copy** email from *Thunderbird Local Folder*  to IMAP account 6) Automating above steps 7) **Profit....**

Answer (score 4):

<sub>SF problem with SU solution :D</sub>

1. Ensure thunderbird computer can't connect to IMAP server (turn off wifi/pull the LAN cable). You don't want to Thunderbird synchronize itself with outdated backup.
2. Run Thunderbird.
3. While offline, copy new email from IMAP account in Thunderbird to [Thunderbird Local Folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Local_Folders). It will backup the email to your computer.
4. Connect thunderbird to IMAP server. Let Thunderbird delete new messages because message doesn't exist in IMAP server.
5. Copy email from [Thunderbird Local Folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Local_Folders) to IMAP account. Restoring our backup then let Thunderbird synchronize itself again but with new email.
6. Automating above steps. Not sure how to do this :)
7. ....other step....
8. **P R O F I T...**

Comment: Note that it will only work for messages that have been downloaded for offline reading on Thunderbird.  Better check that important folders are synchronized (`Account Settings > Synchronization & Storage > Advanced`) before learning it the hard way…  If they were not, you may find useful to keep track of the subject, senders and dates of emails by keeping the current Thunderbird accounts, removing the server name so it can not sync, unchecking "check" checkboxes for convenience and adding back the email accounts as new accounts.